# oracle update from select range

Tags: oracle

I use this sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT a.*, rownum rnum
  FROM (
    SELCT s.id, s.user_id, u.user_id u_id
    FROM sample s
    INNER JOIN template t ON s.t_id = t.t_id
    INNER JOIN user u ON t.u_id = u.u_id
    ORDER BY u.u_id desc
  ) a WHERE rownum <= 100
) WHERE rnum >= 0
```

The sql query result

```
id  user_id  u_id
1   A001     B001
2   A002     B002
3   A003     B003
4   A004     B004
5   A005     B005
```

May I use one sql for php to update the user_id as u_id's value, not use code to run a loop, thanks.

This is I want the result:

```
id  user_id  u_id
1   B001     B001
2   B002     B002
3   B003     B003
4   B004     B004
5   B005     B005
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very simply, without thinking about the complicated `update` statement, you can use `merge` ...

```
merge into sample TGT
using (
  -- your original query starts here
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT a.*, rownum rnum
    FROM (
      SELECT s.id, s.user_id, u.user_id u_id
      FROM sample s
      INNER JOIN template t ON s.t_id = t.t_id
      INNER JOIN user u ON t.u_id = u.u_id
      ORDER BY u.u_id desc
    ) a WHERE rownum <= 100
  ) WHERE rnum >= 0
  -- your original query ends here
) SRC
on ( TGT.id = SRC.id )
when matched then
  update set TGT.user_id = SRC.u_id
;
```

Comment: I have a question, this sql can run on the php?

Comment: No SQL runs in PHP. All SQL runs on the database server. So, yes, you can run this SQL (on your database server) from PHP.

Comment: My mean is use php to execute the sql, like this `$this->db->query($sql)`, the `$sql` is your sql command string.

Comment: Yes, I understand you perfectly. And yes, it will run from PHP.

Comment: If I executed this command by php, and conflict, the sql will die or wait?

Comment: What is "conflict" in your understanding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64367/discussion-between-lll-and-nop77svk).

Comment: If my sql select's id have duplicated, that will cause conflict?

Comment: Yes, in case of duplicate values of `s.id` in the `SRC` dataset the `merge` will fail.

Comment: fail will cause oracle lock or die and exit?

Comment: "Fail" means Oracle will raise an exception and propagate it to your PHP layer, which will catch it and rethrow it as a PHP exception.

Answer (score 1):

You want update table `sample` using table `user` as source?

```
merge into sample s
using (select t.t_id, u.user_id
         from user u, template t
        where u.u_id = t.u_id) u_source
on (u_source.t_id = s.t_id)
when matched then update
set s.user_ud = u_source.user_id
```